# giving a new title to a custom PHP page I cannot modify the (wordpress) HEAD / HEADER of

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I run a website that is part WordPress and part custom coding/scripts and I'm trying to tie them all together visually with the same header and footer.
The Wordpress `get_header()` function works beautifully for that except it always displays my website's title and not the page title (since the header's  section is called before including the custom script.

My question is: is it possible/admissible/workable to somehow add a second  tag (in the body of my custom code) that will take take priority over the previously declared  tag (of the WP header)?

Example of what I have now:

```
<html> // generated by WP
  <head> // generated by WP
    <title>site title</title> // generated by WP
  ... // generated by WP
  </head> // generated by WP
<body> // generated by WP

[custom script included here]  // generated by me
```

could I, inside the  tag, close the body, re-open the head, re-declare the title, close the head and re-open the body like so?

```
<html> // generated by WP
  <head> // generated by WP
    <title>site title</title> // generated by WP
  ... // generated by WP
  </head> // generated by WP
<body> // generated by WP

</body> // generated by me
  <head> // generated by me
    <title>new title</title> // generated by me
  </head> // generated by me
<body> // generated by me

[custom script included here] // generated by me
```

Or is there another/better way to do this that actually works??

I have tried generating the WP header in another page and then inserting the contents into my page via file_get_contents() but then my menu breaks...

Comment: This can be helpful (read the responses)
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/changing-document-title-only-on-a-custom-page-template

Comment: Thank you @AgustínFiori  - that did help and solved my problem!